# Need to calculate data faster

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, worksheet, vba

I am struggling with this code please help me. I want to record change in sheet this code does that but it goes cell by cell which makes it slower. my active sheet runs on 200ms which is very fast by the time this code does its job values changed. is there any way that display values at the same time not by going to each cell. i have so much confusion in my mind please pardon me if my request did not even made any sense.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Const Scope = "G9:H9,G11:H11,G13:H13,G15:H15,G17:H17,G19:H19,G21:H21,G23:H23,G25:H25,G27:H27,G29:H29,G31:H31,G33:H33,G35:H35,G37:H37,G39:H39,G41:H41,G43:H43,G45:H45,G47:H47,G49:H49,G51:H151,G53:H53,G55:H55,G57:H57,G59:H59,G61:H61,G63:H63,G65:H65,G67:H67" ' monitoring area

Static oData As New Dictionary
Dim rCells As Range
Dim oCell
Dim dDelta

Set rCells = Application.Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range(Scope))
If Not rCells Is Nothing Then
    For Each oCell In rCells
        With oCell
            dDelta = oData(.Address)
           .Offset(0, 1).Value = dDelta
            oData(.Address) = .Value
        End With
    Next
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Doing everything in memory with arrays would be faster than making every change directly on the sheet. Also, note that each `Change` on the sheet triggers another `change event`. So, the sub you have coded is calling itself over and over again (recursively). You should turn off events while you make these changes on the sheet. Another point: where is the dictionary `oData` being populated? Please include this portion into the above code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried turning off Screen Updating? Add this line right under your Sub line and see if that helps with the speed at all.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```